# Xampp and Remote Access

Tags: remote, xampp

I have Xampp installed on my Windows 7 laptop so I can work/test a new website.  This is working fine. Because the design is responsive and I want to connect to the Xampp server with a tablet and a cellphone to see how the website is working.

Using the IP address followed by the folder name (192.168.64.1/wordpress) using the phone or the tablet with their standard browsers I can see the homepage but text only and no images. Clicking on the links it gives "webpage not available"

On Opera on the phone and tablet it simply says it cannot connect to the sever.

Most appreciated to any ideas how to sort this out.

Answer (score 0):

One recommended option is possibly using VNC to access your server from a phone possibly? It COULD be an issue with Mobile. Try installing Dolphin Browser and Flash (outdated but works). Also, check your php settings and such; as they could be blocking access to any "foreign" machines.

EDIT: More info is needed for proper diagnostics. Are you trying to access it using the same network or not? 
If not, it is also an issue of port forwarding. You are trying to access a non-public ip without proper set-up. You can enable this by accessing your router and setting it to port-forward or otherwise 'ip-passthrough' your laptop's ip address. Then, instead of typing your lan ip; use your router's ip address .

What this is doing:

You ARE hosting a website; however, this is only running within your private network shared within your own wifi access point. None of these ip exist outside of your own network. For more info try googling 'what is port forwarding' or something of the nature.